# Python typing: mypy is not happy with os.path.dirname and List.remove()

Tags: mypy, python-typing

I have this simple routine where I want to remove some dirs from `$PATH`:

`test.py`

```py
import os
import shutil

# remove babel from PATH
bins = ["babel", "obabel"]
env_path = os.environ["PATH"].split(":")[:]
for abin in bins:
    bpath = shutil.which(abin)
    try:
        rr = os.path.dirname(bpath) # <- mypy error
    except TypeError:
        rr = None
    try:
        env_path.remove(rr) # <- mypy error
    except ValueError:
        pass

os.environ["PATH"] = ":".join(env_path)
```

This does work, however `mypy` complains:

```sh
mypy --ignore-missing-imports test.py

test.py:10: error: Value of type variable "AnyStr" of "dirname" cannot be "Optional[str]"
test.py:14: error: Argument 1 to "remove" of "list" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"
Found 2 errors in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I understand that `bpath` can be a `str` or `None` (hence the `try`), so I tried `bpath: Optional[str]` but that gave me others mypy errors.

Anyway, how to bring peace to `mypy` here?

Comment: Check if `bpath is not None` _before_ trying to call `dirname`? It seems like you're _expecting_ a type error, which means MyPy is pretty certain to be unhappy.

Comment: I think this is one of the situations where asking for permission beats the more pythonic philosophy of asking for forgiveness. Merging the two try-blocks into one if statement appears to be the more elegant solution here and should take care of the typing issues. Oh, and don't use `bin` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in `bin()`.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, based on the suggestions from the comments, this seems to have worked:

```py
for abin in bins:
    bpath = shutil.which(abin)
    if bpath:
        rr = os.path.dirname(bpath)
    else:
        rr = ""
    try:
        env_path.remove(rr)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

No complains from `mypy`.

Comment: I'm still not sure the _logic_ is entirely clear here - is there any point even _attempting_ `env_path.remove(rr)` in the case `rr = ""` (there's probably a more intent-revealing name for that than `rr`)? If not, you can remove the `else` branch entirely and indent the `try` into the `if` suite. Also you should generally check for `None` and other singletons by _identity_ (per e.g. [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)) - `bpath is not None`.